# What does Primordial essence do?

Tags: wolcen

What does primordial essence do? I have this bar in the center of my screen but I don't know how it fills up, what happens when it's full and what its purpose is.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used to switch to a different aspect.

> In order to **shift into your chosen aspect**, you'll have to **collect and
>   have enough Primordial Essence to fill its meter**, and you can **obtain
>   this by killing monsters**. Once it is full, press [R], and you'll shift
>   into your apocalyptic form, the meter will then begin to deplete over
>   time and you'll revert back to your original form once it's empty.

This is something that is unlocked at the end of the first chapter.

> The first aspect can be unlocked near the end of Chapter 1, you'll be
>   given the opportunity to unlock and choose your first aspect, however,
>   as you progress through the game, you can unlock other aspects and
>   players can switch other aspects at any given time once you've
>   obtained a new one.

Source: https://wolcen.wiki.fextralife.com/Aspects